# 2 elements inside 1 div, i want the other element to scale with the first one

Tags: html, css, next.js, tailwind-css

I have a button component with a little accent styling on the left of the button. I want the button to get height based on the content. The "text"-variable could be any text, so it could change any time. i want the button accent to scale with the text, but I can't use 100% or anything like that cause its parent doesnt have any sett height (because I want it to fit content). The button_accent do get height when i set manually, but i want it dynamicly

```
  <div className={`${buttonStyles.button}`} >
    <div className={`${buttonStyles.button_accent} h-full`}></div>
    <div className="mr-3 ml-3 justify-start w-full flex items-center">
      {text}
    </div>
  </div>
```

Button.module.css:

```
.button {
  display: flex;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid #d8fc9133;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: medium;
  background: rgb(128, 128, 128, 0.5);
  align-items: center;
}
.button:hover {
  background: rgb(128, 128, 128, 1);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button_accent {
  width: 12.77px;
  background-color: #d8fc91;
}
```

Heres the button with the accent with height set to 65px. (with no height set, the accent gets 0 height)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `position: relative` to the parent container `.button` and then absolutely position the first div `.button_accent` relative to the parent. This way you don't need to set any explicit [absolute length unit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units) for the `height` value of `.button_accent` but now can use `height: 100%` and let the accent container grow or "scale" to match the height of its parent.

If you remove the text content you will see that the accent still displays and scales to fill its parent which is forced to be at minimum 80px in height from your `min-height: 80px` declaration. When you get rid of this explicit `min-height` and there isn't text content in the `<td>`, the accent mark wont display as the parents content box is empty with zero height.

After positioning the elements, we can use `height: 100%` or another relative length unit for the accent to scale with the text because its absolutely positioned relative to the parent container which is a flexbox and has a `auto` height and `min-height` of 80px. If you don't want the accent to occupy 100% of the parent containers height, but to have some top/bottom space like shown in your included image, just use `height: 80%` or some [relative length unit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#numbers_lengths_and_percentages) to size the accent to your liking.

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid #d8fc9133;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: medium;
  background: rgb(128, 128, 128, 0.5);
  align-items: center;
}
.button:hover {
  background: rgb(128, 128, 128, 1);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button div:last-child {
  margin: 0 1.5rem;
}

.button_accent {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 12.77px;
  height: 80%; /* 100% fills entire height of parent */
  background-color: #d8fc91;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
    <div class="button_accent"></div>
    <div class="mr-3 ml-3 justify-start w-full flex items-center">
      Some text
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: @KimVu Does this help answer your question?